# segment an IP Address generating /8, /16 and /24

Tags: r, networking, ip

Via R and using RStudio, I'm trying to segment an ip address (eg.: 10.10.10.7) and generate a **/8** > **/16** > **/24** > **/32**.

Edit:
My input is a list with +/- 100 IPs and have repeated IPs. The output I want would be a single json, xml, or dataframe with masking segmentation.

Eg.:

```
10.0.0.0
----10.10.0.0
--------10.10.10.0
------------10.10.10.7
--------10.10.20.0
------------10.10.20.7
```

What I've been able to do so far is separate each one into a different dataframe.

I would like to do everything in "one" json or xml or dataframe.

It would be possible? Thanks in advance for the help !!

Comment: What's your input and what output do you want? If you are just trying to split a string on a dot, `strsplit` can do that.

Comment: hello @cory, I updated post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the desired output format, but you can use my [ipaddress](https://davidchall.github.io/ipaddress) R package like so:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ipaddress)

tibble(ip = ip_address(c("10.10.10.7", "10.10.20.7"))) %>%
  mutate(
    net_32 = ip_network(ip, prefix_length = 32L),
    net_24 = supernet(host, new_prefix = 24L),
    net_16 = supernet(host, new_prefix = 16L),
    net_8 = supernet(host, new_prefix = 8L)
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>           ip        net_32        net_24       net_16      net_8
#>    <ip_addr>    <ip_netwk>    <ip_netwk>   <ip_netwk> <ip_netwk>
#> 1 10.10.10.7 10.10.10.7/32 10.10.10.0/24 10.10.0.0/16 10.0.0.0/8
#> 2 10.10.20.7 10.10.20.7/32 10.10.20.0/24 10.10.0.0/16 10.0.0.0/8
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Network classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (two years before the commercial Internet!) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). We have not used network classes in this century, and `10.10.10.0/24` was never a Class C address anyway, and neither was `10.10.0.0/16` a Class B network. Network classes were defined by the first bits of the address. Any address starting with `0`, such as your examples, were Class A addresses, but if the mask is longer than the native class mask, a subnet of the class, not a different class.

Comment: See [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/51918/8499) for how network classes were defined before being deprecated.